# converting raw data from fingerPrint devince into byte array with ISO 19794-2

Tags: c#, .net

I have data coming from `fingerprint` device.

and it's in raw format.

I need to convert it into byte array.

I can do something like this

```
  Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-19794-2");

  byte[] bytes = iso.GetBytes(thunb);
```

but above c# code throws exception that `ISO 19794-2` is not available in Encoding class.

I am getting data from device using its sdk in javascript. but sdk (Secugen) does not has any mechanism for converting raw data into byte array that uses `ISO 19794-2`

I need working solution or good explanation to guide me to achive what I want

thanks

Comment: Do you have the ISO 19794-2 specification? It's not a text encoding as such but a standard. Read up on it and I Think you'll find your solution there.

Comment: I read but could not find any useful help